# Delete an item in the source list from a flutter ListView

Tags: flutter

I'm starting to learn Flutter and I'm trying to write an application.

The application has a list of players in a ListView of SwitchListTile. This is working at the moment. I'm trying to add a function to delete one of the players from the lists.

```
class PlayersSwitchListTilesContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  PlayersSwitchListTilesContainer({this.players});

  final List<PlayerModel> players;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children : players.map<Widget>((PlayerModel p){
           return PlayerSwtichListTile(singlePlayer: p);
        }).toList()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlayerSwtichListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  PlayerSwtichListTile({this.singlePlayer});

  final PlayerModel singlePlayer;

  void removePlayer()
  {
    //  What goes here ???
    print('Delete ' + singlePlayer.playerName);
  }

  @override
  _PlayerSwtichListTileState createState() => new _PlayerSwtichListTileState(player: singlePlayer);
}
```

At the moment, when I try to delete a player it calls the correct code and prints the player's name. However, I'm struggling to see how to delete the player from the `players` list.

I'd be grateful for any pointers anyone has

Comment: You should use `ListView.builder`.

Comment: setState also works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter delete item from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142992/flutter-delete-item-from-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, to delete a player from the list of players you can do this but for this method, you need to provide the index number manually:

```
setState(() {
  players.removeAt(index);
});
```

A better approach would be to use a listView.builder and add a button to the PlayerSwtichListTile which can receive the index from listView.builder so that whenever you click that button then that PlayerSwtichListTile player would get removed:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: players.length ?? 0,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return PlayerSwtichListTile(singlePlayer: p, index: index);}
)

class PlayerSwtichListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  PlayerSwtichListTile({this.singlePlayer, this.index});
  final int index;

  final PlayerModel singlePlayer;

  @override
  _PlayerSwtichListTileState createState() => new _PlayerSwtichListTileState(player: singlePlayer);
}

class _PlayerSwtichListTile extends State<PlayerSwtichListTile > {

  var player;
  _PlayerSwtichListTile({this.player});

  //call this function in ontap of that delete button
  void removePlayer()
  {
    setState(() {
    players.removeAt(widget.index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. Life got in the way. Thank you, this gave me the solution I required